# How Can We Invalidate a Session Automatically When a User is No Longer Active in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web

Can any please tell me that how we can invalidate a session of a user when user is no longer active on a web application for more than 15 minutes in java?

Comment: Search "session timeout"? :|

Answer (score 8):

1. write below code in your web.xml

   ```
   <!-- Session Configuration -->
   <session-config>
           <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   ```

   By providing session time out in your web configuration file you can
   maintain your session time out according to your need
2. You can manually specified the timeout value in “second” for a
   particular session.

   ```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);
   ```

   The above setting is only apply on session which call the
   “setMaxInactiveInterval()” method, and session will be kill by
   container if client doesn’t make any request after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

2 ways to do it :

1. Get the session object from request scope using

   `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` and then `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`
2. Second way to do it is specify it in deployment descriptor (web.xml)

   ```
   <session-config>
   <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   ```

   **Difference between them:**
   The setting in the web.xml is global, it applies to all sessions of a given context. Programatically, you can change this for a particular session.

Answer (score 4):

you can use session.setMaxInactive(15*60);

read the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

In your web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```